Function becomes jagged when being multiplied with a very small prefactor
When I try to scale down a sigmoidal function by multiplying it with a very small value, the function seems to lose its precision, as the curve in the plot becomes jagged lines. The code of the function:
stepFunc[x_] = 0.5*(Tanh[10*x] + 1);
filterFunc[x_] = stepFunc[x - 3]*stepFunc[-(x - 6)];
a = 1*10^(-30);

Plotting the original and scaled function:
Plot[{filterFunc[x]}, {x, 0, 9}, PlotRange -> Full]
Plot[{a*filterFunc[x]}, {x, 0, 9}, PlotRange -> Full]


Plotting the derivative of the original and scaled function:
Plot[{filterFunc'[x]}, {x, 0, 9}, PlotRange -> {-5, 5}]
Plot[{a*filterFunc'[x]}, {x, 0, 9}, 
 PlotRange -> {-5*10^(-30), 5*10^(-30)}]


Noticeably, the function derivative is worse, as the derivative values of the scaled function do not even map to the ones of unscaled function.

try adding PlotPoints -> 500 to the second plot. There might be other options to try but this seems to fix it. V 14  https://i.sstatic.net/pBy759sf.png

You're running into precision problems. This happens with any computing software. Why do you want to do this? Typically, you want to choose units on your quantities so that the numbers you plug into a computer are of order 1.

What do you mean by "the derivative values of the scaled function do not even map to the ones of unscaled function"?

@azerbajdzan This means that there are differences in numerical value of the derivative of the scaled and unscaled functions, if we theoretically unscale back the scaled function. For example, at x=3, the unscaled derivative is more than 4, but the scaled derivative is less than 4*prefactor.

@Nasser This method works fine, thank you so much.

@march I do this to check the influence of a part from a long expression in my main code.
